# MarkLogic migration

Tags: marklogic

I have a MarkLogic server on an ec2 linux 7. I want to migrate it to a linux 6. I moved the ebs to the new linux 6 and mounted it on `/var/opt/MarkLogic`.

I am able to start MarkLogic and access the admin page using web. All looked great until I started getting errors today. I am new to MarkLogic.

```
500: Internal Server Error
XDMP-LEXVAL: db:database-id("") -- Invalid lexical value ""
 In /MarkLogic/Admin/lib/nav-format.xqy on line 181
 In get-databases("")

$icon = ""
$databases = <databases xsi:schemaLocation="http://marklogic.com/xdmp/database database.xsd" xml:lang="zxx" timestamp="14682485897919660" xmlns="http://marklogic.com/xdmp/database" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><database><database-name>Documents</database-name><database-id>1...</databases>
$g = <database xmlns="http://marklogic.com/xdmp/database"  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><database-name>8080-canonicalHL7-modules</database-name><databas...</database>
```

In `/MarkLogic/Admin/lib/nav-format.xqy` on line 884
   In `database-nav("database", "summary", (), "")`

```
$section = "database"
$panel = "summary"
$param = ()
$icon = ""
```

In `/MarkLogic/Admin/lib/nav-format.xqy` on line 2353
   In `printNav("database", "summary", (), "")`

```
$section = "database"
$panel = "summary"
$param = ()
$icon = ""
$sec = "database"
$start-time = xs:dayTimeDuration("PT0.001535S")
```

In `/MarkLogic/Admin/lib/database-summary-form.xqy` on line 123
  In

```
databaseSummaryPage(<databases xsi:schemaLocation="http://marklogic.com/xdmp/database database.xsd" xml:lang="zxx" timestamp="14682485897919660" xmlns="http://marklogic.com/xdmp/database" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><database><database-name>Documents</database-name><database-id>1...</databases>, ())

$datanode = <databases xsi:schemaLocation="http://marklogic.com/xdmp/database database.xsd" xml:lang="zxx" timestamp="14682485897919660" xmlns="http://marklogic.com/xdmp/database" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><database><database-name>Documents</database-name><database-id>1...</databases>
$msgs = ()
```

In /database-summary.xqy on line 17

Answer (score 2):

Looks like in your moving data around you've corrupted your on-disk configuration setup and/or data so now it has an empty string database id, which is choking some admin code which doesn't expect that to ever be able to happen.  It's not a code issue, it's that the configuration data on disk isn't entirely consistent.  Maybe you moved some data but not all.  Maybe you did all this data moving while the server was running.  I can't tell from here.

You say you're new to MarkLogic, so this is probably just a dev server, so my advice would be to simply start fresh.

Comment: thanks for the response. If I use rsync to sync /var/opt/Marklogic to an attached volume. then detach the volume and attach it to the new marklogic server. Should this work?

Comment: I think the most important takeaway is to stop MarkLogic services on both ends, copy the entire Data directory (including Forests, xml config files, and anything else inside there), and only then relaunch services..

Comment: It actually worked this time. Since rsync is best as copying data while server is running. I attached a second volume and synced the entire Marklogc directory to it. detached it and attached it to a new ec2 instance with marklogic installed. and It worked like magic.